# Reset role inheritance on a folder

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm playing around with setting and resetting custom permissions on folders to get an idea of how this works for a script I'm planning to write to do this in bulk.  I am having trouble with ResetRoleInheritance.

I connect to the SharePoint site using `Connect-PnPOnline` and then do this:

```
$FolderURL = 'Shared Documents/General/Test Folder 2'
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderURL -Includes ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```

This returns `False` as expected as I haven't broken inheritance yet.

Then I do:

```
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($True,$True)
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderURL -Includes ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```

This returns `True` as expected.

Then I do this:

```
$Folder.ResetRoleInheritance
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderURL -Includes ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```

This still returns `True` so the inheritance hasn't been reset.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the amd could be:

```
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.ResetRoleInheritance()
$folder.Update() 
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderURL -Includes 
ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```